# Tkinter how to change the color of treeview selected and tagged items

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, ttk

I use a Treeview widget with a list of elements. The user can select one or more element and their foreground shall become red in case of error and remain in the default style otherwise.

There is an interference between the two rules

- The foreground color set by the tag (tagged `=>` red).
- The foreground color set by the style under a specific state (selected `=>` white).

The first one is overridden by the second one, and I would like it to be otherwise.

In summary, here is the difference between what I expect and what I get:

| iid | Selected | Tagged | Expected | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | No | No | Black | Black |
| 2 | No | Yes | Red | Red |
| 3 | Yes | No | White | White |
| 4 | Yes | Yes | Red | White |

Here is a minimal example showing the issue:

```python
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk

mainWindow = tkinter.Tk()
tree = ttk.Treeview(mainWindow)
tree.grid(row=0, column=0)
tree.tag_configure("error", foreground='red')
# Insert elements
for i in '1234':
    tree.insert('', 'end', iid=i, text=i)
# Set tag / selection
for i in '24':
    tree.item(i, tags=['error'])
tree.selection_set(tuple('34'))

mainWindow.mainloop()
```

I already looked at [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58159794/tkinter-how-to-change-the-color-of-treeview-selected-items) which differs from my case because the user wanted to change the color from *all* the selected items, not just the tagged ones.

These issues [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58063067/unable-to-change-background-color-of-treeview-in-python/58094724#58094724) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56329342/tkinter-treeview-background-tag-not-working?rq=3) are different because they refers to [a bug](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tk/tktview?name=509cafafae) affecting Tkinter v8.6.9, fixed in v8.6.10, and I have the version v8.6.12. What I understood from the description of those issues is that in case 2, the color would have remain white.

Comment: I don't see your snippet related to the issues you posted. You don't use style at all. Why do you expect that the selected foreground color is overwritten by your tag? In the bug report you linked they discuss if tags should have a higher priority to style map, but they don't, which I agree with. Read *fvogel added on 2018-11-21 19:14:14:* in the report.